# QGIS Composer causing QGIS to crash when opening a certain template

Tags: qgis, print-composer, rendering

Every time I try to open a certain template in the Print Composer, I get a blank window and no response from the program. 
This then causes the whole program to crash.

This particular template is rather important and I need to access it, one of the possible causes of the crash could be the big amount of maps in the template and the rendering required. However, this issue has only just arisen as last I tried to open the template it was working fine. 
Any advice or potential fixes?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: Can you share the template for a test in another machine?

Comment: Check in Settings > Options > Acceleration if the option Enable OpenCL acceleration  is selected. This could help your rendering. Also, check, again in Options the Tab Rendering. In the top you can select how many CPU Cores you want to use for rendering.

Comment: It's version 3.10.2. How would i go about sharing the template without converting it to a PDF?

Comment: I should also state that QGIS is being ran on a remote computer.